# Add or Remove menu items to drop down with screen size using JS

Tags: javascript, dropdown

How to  add menu items to a drop down depending on the screen size using

**jQuery**

Say i have a menu with eight items. When the eight item fit on the screen  in **one line** then it' ok . But when i re-size the screen the **only** item/items

that do not fit in the screen in **one line** should form a drop-down. when i enlarge again the screen the  menu item should come back one by one & the drop-down should disappear when all the items are fit in the screen .

On an iphone/ipad etc it may even  fit only 2/3 items or so, and the rest should form into a dropdown, dependent on the screen size.

see the link:

http://1drv.ms/1OGYCgS

Comment: You need to use css media queries

Comment: Can't do this with just css as the number of elements will change based on the size of the screen as the OP stated, Can you provide us with some code of what you have tried? you'll need javascript to pull the screen size and push and pop elements from your dropdown as the screensize shrinks/grows.

Comment: It could be done with only css. And it should.

Comment: I refuse to give a 3 line post,  code as an answer but could you please elaborate on how you would do this with css as i am unaware of the ability to dynamically populate dropdowns from css.

Comment: I think it could be done with javascript pretty good rather than only css  .With css you have to design for every screen with ,and it's pain full i think.

Comment: the widths are consisten right?

Answer (score 0):

I think [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) might be a nice alternative for this. 
Sorry if you have considered this and wanted to avoid it.
If you resize the result window, you should see what your after.

You can also specify screen sizes which is then useful, for cross platform availability

Comment: appreciate your help but i want to do it with javascript(jquery i choose ) . look at my image . i have added i link .